# Remove item from Option for Select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an option for select that holds the following values:

[image]

I am wanting to remove the item "Paul Chemello". So I have this:

```
$('secondary-case-managers option[value="Paul Chemello"]').remove();
```

But it is not removing it. Any ideas? Here is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selectedOption = $("#duplicate_claim_case_manager").val();
    if(selectedOption == "Case Manager") {
        $("[for='duplicate_claim_manager_secondary']").css({display: "block"})
        $("#secondary-case-managers").css({display: "block"})
    }
});
$('secondary-case-managers option[value="Case Manager"]').remove();
```

HAML:

```
  = select_tag('duplicate_claim_manager_secondary', options_for_select(@case_managers_drop_down, config.configuration_value),name: "config[#{config.id}]", :include_blank => true, :id=> "secondary-case-managers", :style=>"display:none")
```

Comment: You're missing the `#` in `$('secondary-case-managers`. Your remove call also appears to be outside the document ready function which could be an issue.

Answer (score 3):

You're selector is incorrect. To reference by ID, you need to use '#':

```
$('#secondary-case-managers option[value="Paul Chemello"]').remove();
```

**Additional Info**

If you'd like to brush up on your selectors, you can find the jQuery docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).